# Lithuanian characters in button label not displaying correctly

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I tried change button label to use Lithuanian characters, but form builder does not display them correctly. Is there something in Oracle Form Builder I need to change to correctly show these characters?

Comment: What is your database Encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the NLS_LANG settings of your Oracle home. On windows you can find this in the registery under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE/. If it is something like AMERICAN_AMERICA. please do change it to something like AMERICAN_LITHUANIA... At the same time make sure that the character set part of NLS_LANG is set to a character set that is containing your Lithuanian characters. **On second though this character set setting is most like the cause of your problem.**